# Undefined Local Variable or Method - Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a resource in my application that seems correct but when I open index, I get an error: `undefined local variable or method 'new_beta_request_path'`.  This happens with `beta_request_approval path` also.

My links look like `<%= link_to 'New Beta Request', new_beta_request_path, :class => "btn" %>` and `<%= link_to "Approve", beta_request_approval_path %>`.

All of the paths seem correct to me but something is obviously missing...

In my `routes.rb`, I have:

```
resources :beta_requests, :only => [:index, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]

match '/request_invite', to: 'beta_requests#new', :as => "request_invite"
match 'beta_requests/:id/approve', to: 'beta_requests#approve', :as => "beta_request_approval", :via => :put
```

When I run Rake Routes, I get the following:

```
beta_requests         GET    /beta_requests(.:format)              beta_requests#index
                      POST   /beta_requests(.:format)              beta_requests#create
edit_beta_request     GET    /beta_requests/:id/edit(.:format)     beta_requests#edit
beta_request          PUT    /beta_requests/:id(.:format)          beta_requests#update
                      DELETE /beta_requests/:id(.:format)          beta_requests#destroy
request_invite               /request_invite(.:format)             beta_requests#new
beta_request_approval POST   /beta_requests/:id/approve(.:format)  beta_requests#approve
```

Can anyone see what I apparently cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `:new` in the `only` array? You can either add it:

```
resources :beta_requests, :only => [:index, :edit, :new, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

or remove the hash argument entirely, since this way all resource actions are defined anyway.

Comment: I moved `:new` down below into the `request_invite` path because I didn't want the URL to be `/beta_requests/new`, I wanted `/request_invite`.

Comment: Why don't you use `request_invite_path` instead of `new_beta_request_path` in the first `link_to` call?

Comment: That worked for the `new_beta_request_path` error.  I am still getting the error with the `beta_request_approval_path`.  Could it be that I am using a custom route with the resources routing?

Comment: You haven't specified the HTTP method. If would be `link_to ... :method => :put` or `link_to ... :method => :post`.

Comment: I do have it in the routing file, do I need to add it to the `link_to` tag also?

Comment: Yes. Just like a route can handle one or several methods, a link can use any method (with JavaScript's assistance), and it's GET by default.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `request_invite_path` instead of `new_beta_request_path` in your link. That is:

`<%= link_to 'New Beta Request', request_invite_path, :class => "btn" %>`

This is available to you, since you set the :as option on the request_invite route definition.

As for the other error, I notice that your rake routes lists `beta_request_approval` as using the POST verb and your `routes.rb` defines that route using a `:via => :put` option.

Comment: I already have that in the code.  It might have been a little buried but it is in there: `match '/request_invite', to: 'beta_requests#new', :as => "request_invite"`

Comment: I meant in your view. I updated my answer for clarity. Sorry for the confusion.